# Cancel button press if user moves finger off button

Tags: android, button, ontouchlistener

Here is my very standard button onTouchListener:

```
b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            b.setPressed(true);
        }
        if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            b.setPressed(false);
            // Do the button action stuff here
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

When the user presses down on the button I set the button to "pressed". When the user lifts the finger I set the button to "not pressed" and then do the stuff the button is supposed to do.

This is all great except for the case where the user presses the button and then, while continuing to keep the finger down, moves the finger outside of the button area. When the finger is lifted the ACTION_UP stuff runs anyway. I would like for this behavior to act as a "cancel" of the button press. So, as soon as the pressed finger moves outside the button area I'd like to `b.setPressed(false);` and then NOT do the button action stuff when the finger is raised.

I've tried using `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE` (as suggested by [How to detect when finger slides off the ImageButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414873/how-to-detect-when-finger-slides-off-the-imagebutton)) but I must be missing something because they're not working.

From [Detect when a user moves off of a button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849213/detect-when-a-user-moves-off-of-a-button-in-android) it would appear that this can be done with `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`. If getX() is negative you're off the left and if getY() is negative you're off the top, but to figure out if you're off the right or bottom I'll have to figure out the size of the button and then... there has to be a simpler way. Is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the right answer. Use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get the width and height and check if x or y is greater.

`ACTION_CANCEL` doesn't work because `CANCEL` is generated when a parent view takes control of the touch events, like a `ListView` does when scrolling.

`ACTION_OUTSIDE` only happens in some unusual cases where you request it. It isn't going to be generated for just a normal `MOVE` or `UP`.

Comment: Thank you. getX() and get(y) isn't going to be a huge amount of work, but I'm surprised that there is no "built in" way to do this since it seems like such an obvious button feature. Thanks to whoever gave the downvote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414873/how-to-detect-when-finger-slides-off-the-imagebutton seems to desribe a similiar situation and ACTION_CANCEL apparently worked. Perhaps I don't understand what's going on there.

Comment: ACTION_CANCEL is generated when a parent view (like a scroll view or listview) takes ownership of touch events-  like when a scroll view thinks you're scrolling.  Unless you're in a similar view you won't see an action cancel here.

Comment: OK, I'll have to accept that there isn't an elegant way of doing this. Still seems odd to me but I guess that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one posted any code, here is one. A Boolean is used to indicate when the respective actions should be performed.

The `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` event is handled to check if the finger is moved out of the bounds. If yes, `b.setPressed(false);` is called and the boolean is used to indicate that `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` shouldn't be fired the next time, ie to cancel the button click.

And in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, call `b.setPressed(false);` only if our boolean doesn't indicate a skip (as mentioned above). And if it does, invert the boolean so that button action stuff would execute the next time.

```
private Boolean notNow = false;
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

b.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            b.setPressed(true);
            rect = new Rect(v.Left, v.Top, v.Right, v.Bottom);
        }
        if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (!notNow){
                b.setPressed(false);
            }
            else //button press canceled
                notNow = false;  
        }
        if((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            if(!notNow)
                if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())){ 
                    // finger moved out of bounds
                    b.setPressed(false);
                    notNow = true; //cancel button press the next time
                }
        }

        return true;
});
```