# Handling the entry and exit of a finger in the button area

Tags: java, android, action, android-button, ontouchlistener

There is a gButton button and there is an onTouch listener:

```
gButton.setOnTouchListener (new View.OnTouchListener () {
    public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
         ...
        } else if (event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        ...
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Something is done with `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` (pressing the button / releasing), but the pressing event occurs only when the button is touched, and if the button was pressed and you take your finger away, nothing will happen (there is no finger tap)

I tried to add below, after `ACTION_DOWN`, other "else if" conditions like `ACTION_OUTSIDE` (I took everything from the page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html), but nothing happened. And yes, I used `If`, not `Switch`

I need to make sure that when I touch the button (if the finger is in the button area at all, even if the first touch was somewhere in the empty area and the finger was moved to the button), some actions were performed (for example, a `Toast` method with the text `"On "`), when you release your finger from the button area or when you move your finger from the button area, other actions were performed (`Toast` with the value of `Off`)

I tried to do this with one of the answers to a similar question by correcting it in my code: [Cancel button press if user moves finger off button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710547/cancel-button-press-if-user-moves-finger-off-button), however, an error [prntscr.com/oghnm2](http://prntscr.com/oghnm2) is displayed, and I do not know where and how to get L, R, T, B, except `getTop()`;

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help,here i had checked mouse pointer location with the btn coordinates, if its location within range printed logs otherwise printed out of area.

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               if(v.getLeft()<=event.getX() && v.getRight()>=event.getX() && v.getTop()<=event.getY() && v.getBottom()>=event.getY()) {
                   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                       Log.d("LOG", "pressed");
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                       Log.d("LOG", "released");
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                       Log.d("LOG", "moving");
               }
               else
               {
                   Log.d("LOG", "out of area");
               }
               return false;
           }
       });
```

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work either: [http://prntscr.com/oh7nvb] [http://prntscr.com/oh7re6]